# Kivy - How do I call a function from the ListView?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm struggling with this one small bit where I cannot find a way to pass a value through a procedure when a ListView item is pressed. The example below is a simpler version of what I want to happen and how my main code is set out. 
The goal is so a can see *ChangeScreen(self.index)* on the hash tagged *on_release:* in the KV file. However the issue is I do not know how to call ChangeScreen successfully. Thanks!

Kivy:

```
#: import main main
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter 

AppScreenManager:
    DemoScreen1:
        id: screen1
    DemoScreen2:
        id: screen2

<DemoScreen1>:
    name: "demoscreen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ListView:
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=["Screen 1","Screen 2"], cls=main.ListButton)

<DemoScreen2>:
    name: "demoscreen2"
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: labText
            text: "Hello World"

<ListButton>:
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    on_release: ### HOW DO I CALL THE ChangeScreen FUNCTION HERE
```

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton


class DemoScreen1(Screen):
    def ChangeScreen(self, option):
        if option == 0:
            print("Screen1")
            self.parent.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 1 was pressed")
        else:
            print("Screen2")
            self.parent.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 2 was pressed")
        self.parent.current = "demoscreen2"

class DemoScreen2(Screen):
    labText = StringProperty()
    def labelUpdater(self,newText):
        self.ids.labText.text = newText

class ListButton(ListItemButton):
    data = ListProperty()

class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Tester(App): 
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tester().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an alternative solution:

```
...
<ListButton>:
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    on_release: self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.ChangeScreen(self.index)

...
```

but just do this for the events like `on_press`, `on_release` never for `on_parent` because they have no parent when this last event is call

for the explanation all you have to know is that `self.parent.parent.parent` is your `ListView`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here what I think you should do:

- `ChangeScreen` method should be moved to `ScreenManager`: it's a
  screen managers who manages screen changes.
- Reaction on changing selection should be placed inside `ListAdapter`:
  list adapter - is a controller that manages what happens on selection with its
  `on_selection_change` event.
  You can achieve it inheriting `ListAdapter` same way as you did with
  `ListItemButton`.
- Placing callbacks calling in kvfile is (IMHO) bad idea: kvfile is sort of view, leave callbacks to cotrollers such as `ListAdapter`. Again it can be achieved inheriting `ListAdapter`.
- Since `ListAdapter` uses `ScreenManager`'s `ChangeScreen` method, adapter should be inited with screen (alternative to it can be as EL3PHANTEN suggested putting `ScreenManager` into App, but it becomes sort of global variable then).

Here's refactored code that contains all suggested above:

**tester.kv**

```
#: import main main

AppScreenManager:
    DemoScreen1:
        id: screen1
    DemoScreen2:
        id: screen2

<DemoScreen1>:
    name: "demoscreen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ListView:
            adapter:
                main.MyListAdapter(
                data=["Screen 1","Screen 2"], 
                cls=main.MyListButton, 
                scr=root.parent
                )

<DemoScreen2>:
    name: "demoscreen2"
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: labText
            text: "Hello World"

<MyListButton>:
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter


class DemoScreen1(Screen):
    pass


class DemoScreen2(Screen):
    labText = StringProperty()
    def labelUpdater(self,newText):
        self.ids.labText.text = newText


class MyListButton(ListItemButton):
    data = ListProperty()


class MyListAdapter(ListAdapter):
    scr = ObjectProperty()

    def on_selection_change(self, *args):
        self.scr.ChangeScreen(self.selection[0].index)


class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def ChangeScreen(self, option):
        if option == 0:
            print("Screen1")
            self.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 1 was pressed")
        else:
            print("Screen2")
            self.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 2 was pressed")
        self.current = "demoscreen2"


class Tester(App): 
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tester().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put the `changeScreen` method in the `ListButton` class instead.
Then make the `ScreenManager` as an attribute in the `App` class. Thet way you can access it as `app.sm` in kv.
Then you can pass `app.sm` to the `ChangeScreen` method, to get the screens.
Here is your modified example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.lang import Builder


class DemoScreen2(Screen):

    def labelUpdater(self,newText):
        self.ids.labText.text = newText


class ListButton(ListItemButton):
    data = ListProperty()

    def ChangeScreen(self, option, sm):
        if option == 0:
            print("Screen1")
            sm.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 1 was pressed")
        else:
            print("Screen2")
            sm.ids.screen2.labelUpdater("Screen 2 was pressed")
        sm.current = "demoscreen2"


class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


KV = """

#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<AppScreenManager>:
    DemoScreen1:
        id: screen1
    DemoScreen2:
        id: screen2

<DemoScreen1@Screen>:
    name: "demoscreen1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ListView:
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=["Screen 1","Screen 2"], cls=Factory.ListButton)

<DemoScreen2>:
    name: "demoscreen2"
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            id: labText
            text: "Hello World"
            on_release:
                app.sm.current = "demoscreen1"

<ListButton>:
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    on_release: root.ChangeScreen(self.index,app.sm)

"""


class Tester(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.sm = AppScreenManager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tester().run()
```